# Code reordering due to optimization

Tags: c++, optimization

I've heard so many times that an optimizer may reorder your code that I'm starting to believe it.
Are there any examples or typical cases where this might happen and how can I Avoid such a thing (eg I want a benchmark to be impervious to this)?

Comment: Some typical cases would be assignments that appear independent from each other, or most anything where it doesn't appear that the ordering matters. Ways to avoid this are to use memory barriers/fences, or atomics. Usually the reorder is ok, but at times you might be writing to a pointer to some hardware component (or something like that...), which is where reordering usually pops up as an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are LOTS of different kinds of "code-motion" (moving code around), and it's caused by lots of different parts of the optimisation process:

- move these instructions around, because it's a waste of time to wait for the memory read to complete without putting at least one or two instructions between the memory read and the operation using the content we got from memory
- Move things out of loops, because it only needs to happen once (if you call `x = sin(y)` once or 1000 times without changing y, `x` will have the same value, so no point in doing that inside a loop. So compiler moves it out.
- Move code around based on "compiler expects this code to hit more often than the other bit, so better cache-hit ratio if we do it this way" - for example error handling being moved away from the source of the error, because it's unlikely that you get an error [compilers often understand commonly used functions and that they typically result in success].
- Inlining - code is moved from the actual function into the calling function. This often leads to OTHER effects such as reduction in pushing/poping registers from the stack and arguments can be kept where they are, rather than having to move them to the "right place for arguments".

I'm sure I've missed some cases in the above list, but this is certainly some of the most common.

The compiler is perfectly within its rights to do this, as long as it doesn't have any "observable difference" (other than the time it takes to run and the number of instructions used - those "don't count" in observable differences when it comes to compilers)

There is very little you can do to avoid compiler from reordering your code - you can write code that ensures the order to some degree. So for example, we can have code like this:

```
{
int sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < large_number; i++)
  sum += i;
}
```

Now, since `sum` isn't being used, the compiler can remove it. Adding some code that checks prints the sum would ensure that it's "used" according to the compiler.

Likewise:

```
 for(i = 0; i < large_number; i++)
 {
     do_stuff();
 }
```

if the compiler can figure out that `do_stuff` doesn't actually change any global value, or similar, it will move code around to form this:

```
 do_stuff();
 for(i = 0; i < large_number; i++)
 {
 }
```

The compiler may also remove - in fact almost certainly will - the, now, empty loop so that it doesn't exist at all. [As mentioned in the comments: If `do_stuff` doesn't actually change anything outside itself, it may also be removed, but the example I had in mind is where `do_stuff` produces a result, but the result is the same each time]

(The above happens if you remove the printout of results in the Dhrystone benchmark for example, since some of the loops calculate values that are never used other than in the printout - this can lead to benchmark results that exceed the highest theoretical throughput of the processor by a factor of 10 or so - because the benchmark assumes the instructions necessary for the loop were actually there, and says it took X nominal operations to execute each iteration)

There is no easy way to ensure this doesn't happen, aside from ensuring that `do_stuff` either updates some variable outside the function, or returns a value that is "used" (e.g. summing up, or something).

Another example of removing/omitting code is where you store values repeatedly to the same variable multiple times:

```
int x;

for(i = 0; i < large_number; i++)
    x = i * i;
```

can be replaced with:

```
x = (large_number-1) * (large_number-1);
```

Sometimes, you can use `volatile` to ensure that something REALLY happens, but in a benchmark, that CAN be detrimental, since the compiler also can't optimise code that it SHOULD optimise (if you are not careful with the how you use `volatile`).

If you have some SPECIFIC code that you care particularly about, it would be best to post it (and compile it with several state of the art compilers, and see what they actually do with it).

[Note that moving code around is definitely not a BAD thing in general - I do want my compiler (whether it is the one I'm writing myself, or one that I'm using that was written by someone else) to make optimisation by moving code, because, as long as it does so correctly, it will produce faster/better code by doing so!]

Comment: @MattMcNabb: True. I was thinking of something where, for example, it fills an array - but the values are the same each time.

Comment: How can it move the `do_stuff()` method?  Very irritating.  If I want to perform an action *N* times, you are saying the compiler will move the action out of the loop and do nothing for *N* times?

Comment: Another code *movement*:  multiple returns of same value.  For example, if a function has many "return successful;", the compiler will pick one and the rest will cause a jump to the location of the return that the compiler picked.

Comment: Also, code duplication within a function.  The compiler may create a subroutine for duplicate code and replace duplications with a call to the subroutine.

Comment: I've never seen the compiler (any compiler) create subroutines out of a larger function - it may well happen, but I've not seen it. And yes, if performing `do_stuff` N times has the same effect as performing it once (aside from the time it takes), then it is allowed to do that. If it has an externally observable effect (such as printing something to the console), then it obviously can't do that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Just wanted to add that in general (not necessarily in this case) there are also CPU optimizations that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, reordering is only allowed in situations where the observable effects of the program are the same - this means you shouldn't be able to tell.

Counterexamples do exist, for example the order of operands is unspecified and an optimizer is free to rearrange things. You can't predict the order of these two function calls for example:

```
int a = foo() + bar();
```

Read up on [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) to see what guarantees are made.

Comment: I'm guessing he means when things are reorded over sequence points (e.g. as raised by scaryrawr,  `a = b; printf("5");` could generate assembly which calls `printf` and then does the assignment)